# Skipping tests when building with composite build in Gradle

Tags: gradle

I have 5 projects that are dependent. So I have made new 'dummy' project that is a [composite build](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/composite_builds.html) of these 5 projects and have the following task:

```
task build {
    dependsOn gradle.includedBuilds*.task(':build')
}
```

I can run the build of all projects in composite using: `gradlew build`? Or how to this in other way?

How can I now pass the `-x test` to skip the test execution for composite build?

Comment: I guess that it's impossible right now, without any dirty hacks.

Comment: I was thinking into adding task dynamically to each included build that would do the build without tests running, but so far no luck

Comment: I had the same idea, but it seems it is not possible to access to the projects of the included builds via Gradle API.

Comment: Any idea from the Gradle developers, seems like a big hole in functionalities.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of trying to exclude tasks (`build` tasks depend on `test`), you can use the `assemble` task instead:

```
task buildWithoutTests {
    dependsOn gradle.includedBuilds*.task(':assemble')
}
```

According to the task listing (`gradle tasks`), the difference is:

```
assemble - Assembles the outputs of this project.
build - Assembles and tests this project.
```